# Two hard drives with windows and linux, windows won't boot

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, multi-boot

I recently installed fedora 17 to one of the hard drives in my computer. Before hand, I had windows 7 on my other hdd in the same computer. Now, when I try to boot the windows 7 hard drive, I get the unknown filesystem grub error followed by the "Grub recovery" command line.  I can boot to my windows seven using hiren's boot cd but this is obviously not practical to do every time. Any way I can fix this if I don't have a install disc?

Comment: Configure grub to boot Linux and Windows. [See here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=237831).

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot into Fedora, log in as root and run these commands:

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This will install GRUB (a linux [bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting)) to the MBR of the primary master hard drive of your system. Unless you have made some strange choices during an installation process, that is what you want to do.

GRUB should detect both Windows and Fedora automatically. At the next reboot you will be presented with a menu allowing you to chose what operating system to boot.